# How to make both input fields and radio buttons parallel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, user-input

I have some user input fields as well as some radio buttons as seen below:
[image]

Am bootstrapping the styling. Tried many ways to make it happen. Anyone please help me suggest a way to do it.. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: provide code what you have tried so far?

Comment: see i created example for you, if you want any help let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example using Bootstrap :

Example: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/7rav8fkd/3/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row radioLabel">
        <label>A</label>
        <label>B</label>
        <label>C</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 well rowCell">
            <label>A</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="radio" name="A" checked />
            <input type="radio" name="B" />
            <input type="radio" name="C" />
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-12 well rowCell">
            <label>B</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="radio" name="A" />
            <input type="radio" name="B" checked/>
            <input type="radio" name="C" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 well rowCell">
            <label>C</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="radio" name="A" />
            <input type="radio" name="B" />
            <input type="radio" name="C" checked />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: @blackwindow you can also provide title to radio

Comment: Yeah. But the radio buttons are so close. I want to keep the radio buttons parallel and keep some space between. Also I want it to be like one div section. With headings on each three set of radio buttons. Can you help me to update your answer based on that..

Comment: @blackwindow see this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/7rav8fkd/3/

Comment: @blackwindow i updated answer now if you want more space then increase padding

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve it using table. Check the follow codes.

See Live: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6rp30aa/)

**HTML:**

```
<table class="t1">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a1" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a1" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a1" id=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a2" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a2" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a2" id=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a3" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a3" id=""></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="a3" id=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table.t1 tr td {
    padding:5px 20px 5px 5px;
}

table.t1 tr td:nth-of-type(1),
table.t1 tr td:nth-of-type(2){
    padding-right: 5px!important;
}
```

Comment: @blackwindow, I have modified my codes a little in order to fulfill your requirements. You can check if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Html table is useful for this case i imagine. Is there any reason why you don't want or can't use a simple table?